# how to make an Intent show up instead of the main Activity when i start the application

Tags: android

Long story short i made a notes app and everything works fine
now i had tried to make a page where it works as a "login page"where you put your username and id and then you can login

now that i made as an intent after i finished the app
how can i make the login page show up instead of my main activity when i open the app?
like is there a `function` that can show an intent instead of the `main activity` when i open the app
help and suggestions are welcome and thanks in advance <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application will always open the activity defined with the `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` intent-filter in the Manifest upon launch. You'll likely want to swap your launch activity to be this new login page and implement some sort of navigation from the login to the main activity instead of vice versa. While it is called the "MainActivity", the name itself doesn't carry any special privileges or functionality in the Android SDK. It's just commonly associated with the launch intent filter. Here I am assuming your login page is also an activity. If this is not the case or you are unsure of how to navigate, I'm happy to help.

Comment: thanks so much @buggily , oh yeah my login page is also an activity i think i can manage with the navigation its not a big deal , the only problem here where in the android studio i can find or shall implemnt this category intent-filter

Comment: oh I found it its in the AndroidManifest but it displays the screen empty oh well another bug to fix haha thanks anyways <3